# compiling error in matrix class experimentation - "expected initializer before ‘.’ token"

Tags: c++, class, matrix, initialization

I'm developing some test code for handling matrices. In the code, matrices are defined by a class which has various functions for multiplying matrices etc. I've run into a difficulty regarding an expected initialiser when compiling. Could you point me in the right direction on this problem?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>

#define Column_Spacing 10;

using namespace std;

class Matrix{
    public: 
        void Output_Matrix(double **, int, int);
        double** Zero_Matrix(int);
        double** Input_Matrix(int);
        void Calculate_Minor(double **, double **, int, int, int);
        double Determinant (double **, int);
        void Matrix_Inversion(double **, double **, int);
};

/*******************************************************************************
function: output matrix

This function is used to output a matrix of arbitrary size. It requires three
arguments: the matrix/matrix location, the number of rows in the matrix and the
number of columns in the matrix.
*******************************************************************************/

void Output_Matrix(double **Matrix, int Number_of_Rows, int Number_of_Columns){
    int Rows_Output_Iterator = 0, Columns_Output_Iterator = 0;
    while (Rows_Output_Iterator < Number_of_Rows){
        while (Columns_Output_Iterator < Number_of_Columns){
            cout << "/t" << Matrix [Rows_Output_Iterator][Columns_Output_Iterator];
            Columns_Output_Iterator++;
        }
        cout << endl;
        Columns_Output_Iterator = 0;
        Rows_Output_Iterator++;
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
function: zero matrix

This function is used to create an arbitrary-sized matrix in which all of its
elements are zero.
*******************************************************************************/

double** Zero_Matrix(int Matrix_Order){
    int Number_of_Rows_Zero, Number_of_Columns_Zero;
    if (Matrix_Order > 0){
        Number_of_Rows_Zero = Matrix_Order;
        Number_of_Columns_Zero = Matrix_Order;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Zero Matrix." << endl;
        cout << "State the number of rows in the zero matrix: ";
        cin >> Number_of_Rows_Zero;
        cout << "State the number of columns in the zero matrix: ";
        cin >> Number_of_Columns_Zero;
    }
    double **Zero_Matrix = new double*[Number_of_Rows_Zero];
    for (int Zero_Matrix_Iterator = 0; Zero_Matrix_Iterator < Number_of_Rows_Zero; Zero_Matrix_Iterator++){
        Zero_Matrix[Zero_Matrix_Iterator] = new double[Number_of_Columns_Zero];
    }
    for (int Row_Iterator = 0; Row_Iterator < Number_of_Rows_Zero; Row_Iterator++){
        for (int Column_Iterator = 0; Column_Iterator < Number_of_Columns_Zero; Column_Iterator++){
            Zero_Matrix[Row_Iterator][Column_Iterator] = 0;
        }
    }
    return Zero_Matrix;
}

/*******************************************************************************
function: input matrix

This function is used to create an arbitrary-sized matrix defined by the used
and to fill it with arbitrary entries specified by the user.
*******************************************************************************/

double** Input_Matrix(int Matrix_Order){
    int Number_of_Rows, Number_of_Columns;
    double Entry;
    cout << "Input Matrix A." << endl;
    if (Matrix_Order > 0){
        Number_of_Rows = Matrix_Order;
        Number_of_Columns = Matrix_Order;
    }
    else{
        cout << "State the number of rows in the matrix: ";
        cin >> Number_of_Rows;
        cout << "State the number of columns in the matrix: ";
        cin >> Number_of_Columns;
    }
    double **Matrix_A = new double*[Number_of_Rows];
    for (int Iterator = 0; Iterator < Number_of_Rows; Iterator++){
        Matrix_A[Iterator] = new double[Number_of_Columns];
    }
    cout << "Entry ij" << endl;
    for (int Row_Iterator = 0; Row_Iterator < Number_of_Rows; Row_Iterator++){
        for (int Column_Iterator = 0; Column_Iterator < Number_of_Columns; Column_Iterator++){
            cout << "Entry " << Row_Iterator << Column_Iterator << ": ";
            cin >> Entry;
            Matrix_A [Row_Iterator][Column_Iterator] = Entry;
        }
    }
    cout << "Matrix A = " << endl;
    Output_Matrix(Matrix_A, Number_of_Rows, Number_of_Columns);
    return Matrix_A;
}

/*******************************************************************************
function: calculate minor

This function calculates the minor of an arbitrary input matrix. This function
requires five arguments: the input matrix, the minor (to store the output
value), the row number (which will be eliminated from the input matrix), the
column number which will be eliminated from the input matrix and the order of
the matrix respectively. 
*******************************************************************************/

void Calculate_Minor(double **Matrix, double **Minor, int Row_Number, int Column_Number, int Matrix_Order){
    int Row_Count = 0, Column_Count = 0;
    for (int Row_Iterator = 0; Row_Iterator < Matrix_Order; Row_Iterator++){
        if (Row_Iterator != Row_Number){
            Column_Count = 0;
            for(int Column_Iterator = 0; Column_Iterator < Matrix_Order; Column_Iterator++){
                if (Column_Iterator != Column_Number){
                    Minor[Row_Count][Column_Count] = Matrix[Row_Iterator][Column_Iterator];
                    Column_Count++;
                }
            }
            Row_Count++;
        }
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
function: determinant

This function calculates the determinant of an arbitrary sized input matrix.
This function requires two arguments/inputs which are the input matrix and the
order of the matrix respectively. This function uses recursion i.e. the function
can, if necessary, be called again suppling the corresponding minors of the
original input matrix until the total determinant has been calculated. This
function requires the use of the function Calculate_Minor.
*******************************************************************************/

double Determinant (double **Matrix, int Matrix_Order){
    double det = 0;
    if (Matrix_Order == 1){
        return Matrix[0][0];
    }
    double **Minor_Matrix = new double*[Matrix_Order - 1];
    for (int Iterator = 0; Iterator < Matrix_Order - 1; Iterator++){
        Minor_Matrix[Iterator] = new double[Matrix_Order - 1];
    }
    for (int Column_Iterator = 0; Column_Iterator <= (Matrix_Order - 1); Column_Iterator++){
        Calculate_Minor(Matrix, Minor_Matrix, 0, Column_Iterator, Matrix_Order);
        det += (Column_Iterator % 2 == 1?-1.0:1.0)*Matrix[0][Column_Iterator]*Determinant(Minor_Matrix, Matrix_Order - 1);
        //det += pow(-1, Iterator_2)*Matrix[0][Iterator_2]*Determinant(Minor, Matrix_Size - 1);
    }
    for (int Iterator = 0; Iterator < (Matrix_Order - 1); Iterator++){
        delete [] Minor_Matrix[Iterator];
    }
    delete [] Minor_Matrix;
    //cout << "det = " << det << endl;
    return det;
}

/*******************************************************************************
function: matrix inversion

This function calculates the inverse of an arbitrary input matrix. This function
requires three arguments/inputs which are the input matrix, the cofactor matrix
(somewhere to store the cumulative output of this function for example a matrix
whose entries are all zero) and the order of the matrix respectively. This
function uses the determinant function and the Calculate_Minor function. 
*******************************************************************************/

void Matrix_Inversion(double **Matrix, double **Cofactor_Matrix, int Matrix_Order){
    if (Determinant(Matrix, Matrix_Order) == 0){
        cout << "The matrix is singular i.e. det(A) = 0 hence, no inverse matrix (A^-1) exists." << endl;
    }
    else{
        double Coefficient = 1/(Determinant(Matrix, Matrix_Order));
        double *Temporary = new double[(Matrix_Order - 1)*(Matrix_Order - 1)];
        double **Minor = new double*[Matrix_Order - 1];
        for (int Iterator = 0; Iterator < (Matrix_Order - 1); Iterator++){
            Minor[Iterator] = Temporary + (Iterator*(Matrix_Order - 1));
        }
        for (int Row_Iterator = 0; Row_Iterator < Matrix_Order; Row_Iterator++){
            for (int Column_Iterator = 0; Column_Iterator < Matrix_Order; Column_Iterator++){
                Calculate_Minor(Matrix, Minor, Row_Iterator, Column_Iterator, Matrix_Order);
                Cofactor_Matrix[Row_Iterator][Column_Iterator] = Determinant(Minor, Matrix_Order - 1);
                if ((Row_Iterator + Column_Iterator)%2 == 1){
                    Cofactor_Matrix[Row_Iterator][Column_Iterator] = -Cofactor_Matrix[Row_Iterator][Column_Iterator];
                }
            }
        }
    double **Cofactor_Transpose = new double*[Matrix_Order];
    for (int Iterator = 0; Iterator < Matrix_Order; Iterator++){
        Cofactor_Transpose[Iterator] = new double[Matrix_Order];
    }
    for (int Row_Iterator = 0; Row_Iterator < Matrix_Order; Row_Iterator++){
        for (int Column_Iterator = 0; Column_Iterator < Matrix_Order; Column_Iterator++){
            Cofactor_Transpose[Column_Iterator][Row_Iterator] = Cofactor_Matrix[Row_Iterator][Column_Iterator];
        }
    }
    double **Inverse_Matrix = new double*[Matrix_Order];
    for (int Iterator = 0; Iterator < Matrix_Order; Iterator++){
        Inverse_Matrix[Iterator] = new double[Matrix_Order];
    }
    for (int Row_Iterator = 0; Row_Iterator < Matrix_Order; Row_Iterator++){
        for (int Column_Iterator = 0; Column_Iterator < Matrix_Order; Column_Iterator++){
            Inverse_Matrix[Column_Iterator][Row_Iterator] = Coefficient*Cofactor_Matrix[Row_Iterator][Column_Iterator];
        }
    }
    cout << "(Inverse Matrix) A^-1 = " << Coefficient << endl;
    Output_Matrix(Cofactor_Transpose, Matrix_Order, Matrix_Order);
    cout << "= " << endl;
    Output_Matrix(Inverse_Matrix, Matrix_Order, Matrix_Order);
    delete [] Temporary;
    delete [] Minor;
    delete [] Cofactor_Transpose;
    delete [] Inverse_Matrix;
}
}

int main(){
    int Matrix_Order = 0;
    cout << "Define the order of the input matrix (... if the input matrix is square - if not, set this variable to zero): ";
    cin >> Matrix_Order;
    Matrix Matrix_A, Cofactor_Matrix, determinant, Matrix_Inverse;
    double **Matrix_A.Input_Matrix(Matrix_Order);
    /*
    double **Cofactor_Matrix.Zero_Matrix(Matrix_Order);
    double det = determinant.Determinant(Matrix_A, Matrix_Order);
    cout << "(Determinant) det = " << det << endl;
    Matrix_Inverse.Matrix_Inversion(Matrix_A, Cofactor_Matrix, Matrix_Order);
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about telling us which line number the error refers to.

Comment: The first error is at line 5.

Comment: why do you have an argument in the Output_Matrix method having the same name as a class?

Comment: Please trim down this wall of code as far as possible. Otherwise, it's hard to spot the problem.

Comment: This line `double **Matrix_A.Input_Matrix(Matrix_Order);` makes no sense. What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your class definition :

```
class Matrix{
public: 
    void Output_Matrix(double **, int, int);
    double** Zero_Matrix(int);
    double** Input_Matrix(int);
    void Calculate_Minor(double **, double **, int, int, int);
    double Determinant (double **, int);
    void Matrix_Inversion(double **, double **, int);
};
```

Instead of this line in your implemented methods :

```
void Output_Matrix(double **Matrix, int Number_of_Rows, int Number_of_Columns){ ... }
```

You should write the following :

```
void Matrix::Output_Matrix(double **Matrix, int Number_of_Rows, int Number_of_Columns){...}
```

You have to add `Matrix::` like I did to each of your class member implementation.

In your `main`, you wrote this line :

```
double **Matrix_A.Input_Matrix(Matrix_Order);
```

This makes no sense. I'd suggest you to use `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` instead of `double**`. Then you can write : `typedef std::vector<std::vector<double> > MATRIX;`.

As an example, the line in your main will be : `MATRIX M = Matrix_A.Input_Matrix(Matrix_Order);`.

[Utilities about std::vector in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Let's do an example for your `Input_Matrix` method :

```
MATRIX Matrix::Input_Matrix(int Matrix_Order){
    int Number_of_Rows, Number_of_Columns;
    double Entry;
    cout << "Input Matrix A." << endl;
    if (Matrix_Order > 0){
        Number_of_Rows = Matrix_Order;
        Number_of_Columns = Matrix_Order;
    }
    else{
        cout << "State the number of rows in the matrix: ";
        cin >> Number_of_Rows;
        cout << "State the number of columns in the matrix: ";
        cin >> Number_of_Columns;
    }
    MATRIX Matrix_A;
    Matrix_A.resize(Number_of_Rows); 
    for (int Iterator = 0; Iterator < Number_of_Rows; Iterator++){
        Matrix_A[Iterator].resize(Number_of_Columns);
    }
    cout << "Entry ij" << endl;
    for (int Row_Iterator = 0; Row_Iterator < Number_of_Rows; Row_Iterator++){
        for (int Column_Iterator = 0; Column_Iterator < Number_of_Columns; Column_Iterator++){
            cout << "Entry " << Row_Iterator << Column_Iterator << ": ";
            cin >> Entry;
            Matrix_A[Row_Iterator][Column_Iterator] = Entry;
        }
    }
    cout << "Matrix A = " << endl;
    /* First parameter of the following method must be of type MATRIX. */
    Output_Matrix(Matrix_A, Number_of_Rows, Number_of_Columns); 

    return Matrix_A;
}
```

Now, you'll be able to do the rest following this example. Hope this will help you.